# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition do not work in Firefox 30.0

Tags: firefox, geolocation, navigator

I am using Firefox 30.0 (latest FF), and `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is working in Chrome but not in this version of FF.

Here is my code:

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GEOprocess, GEOdeclined);
}else{
    alert('Your browser sucks. Upgrade it.');
}

function GEOdeclined(error) {
    alert('Error: ' +error.message);
}

function GEOprocess(position) {
    alert('it works');
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Unknown error acquiring position
```

Note: It stopped working after upgrading Firefox to version 30.0

Answer (score 29):

Now I'm using 47 Mozilla. I have tried everything, but all time this problem.
**BUT** then I open **about:config** in my address bar, go **geo.wifi.uri** and changed its value to "https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=test".
works!

Comment: Changing the uri worked for me too, seems like google is blocking something.

Comment: but client need to do setting for geolocation, is there any way to modify that setting through coding or instead of setting can we get geolocation through other way

Comment: @Abhijit Jagtap i needed it only for my local environment.

Comment: Thanks @VasylGutnyk for a reply, but do you have any idea, how do I implement it at client side?

Comment: @Abhijit Jagtap 
didn't work with smth like that.
but maybe this library can help u: https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/

Comment: The config key has changed from "geo.wifi.uri" to "geo.provider.network.url". I'm using FF 76

Answer (score 2):

I've a possible solution:

I think that the mozilla guys have change something in the location adquisition process, so now it take more time and the function getCurrentPosition gets a timeout.

This will answer the question of why it works in chrome, worked in FF 29 and not in FF 30.0.

But thats a suposition. Now let's get back to the real world:

I've put a timeout of 10 seconds on the call and now it works. I've done it this way:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout:10000});
```

This fixed it for me. It works on FF 30.