# Mozilla geolocation has worked fine for weeks but now "Unable to get location: Unknown error acquiring position" | Still works on Chrome, IE and Edge

Tags: html, debugging, geolocation, mozilla

We're creating a small project where one part is getting your location. It has worked fine for the past weeks on Chrome, Mozilla, Edge and IE but all of a sudden Mozilla stopped working. I get the error message: "Unable to get location: Unknown error acquiring position".

I tried previous commits where it certainly worked before but still no luck. Has anyone stumbled upon this before? What could it be?

It's my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so I might not get the question structure right :)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359073/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-do-not-work-in-firefox-30-0