# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition returns "Unknown error acquiring position"

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

I'm working currently with the geolocation API.

When allowing my browser - localhost or webhost- to fetch my position, my console.log returns :

> Unknown error acquiring position

I can't figure out since I have authorized the connection and my code seems to be clean since I have fetched it from the Mozilla official MDN.

Here my client.js :

```
      var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
      };

      function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;

        console.log('Votre position actuelle est :');
        console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
        console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
        console.log(`Plus ou moins ${crd.accuracy} mètres.`);
      };

      function error(err) {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
      };

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

any hint would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google has changed (May-June) some policies on API key (now a valid API key is required). If you go to Firefox and type `about:config` and search for property  `geo.wifi.uri`, you'll see google url with no api key. You can change the url to another geo service (https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=test), but for production, it is better to perform direct ajax call as below:

```
    const res = await fetch('https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=test').then(el=>el.json())
    const point = [res.location.lat, res.location.lng]
```

Once Firefox solves the issue you could go back to use the geolocation API as before.

(see also [html geolocation: Unknown error acquiring position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773259/html-geolocation-unknown-error-acquiring-position?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is what I use to get my users lat/lng

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    var pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log("Lat: " + pos.lat + ". Lng: " + pos.lng);
  })
}
```

This uses the browsers geolocation and returns the users lat and lng. Then I use google's  reversegeocoding to get the actual address.

Comment: thanks, it returns me nothing so far, like "null", no log, nothing

Comment: What browser are you using? And does that browser allow sharing the users location?

Comment: yep I have just installed Chrome, it works fine on Chrome but not on other browsers - Firefox 61.0.1 _ Opera  54.0.2952.54 -, surely a browser's issue so

Comment: I have installed Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99 more precisely. And I'm connect with my ethernet cable, wifi not enabled I think in my devices, I had problem with an issue about my hardware and Ubuntu 16.04 seems

Comment: That really shouldn't be a problem, have you tried checking if the firefox has privacy mode off and it grants the website the users location. I just tested on firefox and Edge on windows 10 and this code worked like a charm. Firefox did have a little bit of a delay but nothing major.